# I am trying to create a minigame map on bedrock version of minecraft and I need a way of detecting death

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Now for most of the games when you start you get given a tag so that the other commands don't just `@p` and they actually have `@p[tag="game_tag"]` so it affects the right people.

There has to a way to detect death on Bedrock Minecraft but all the tutorials I have seen are for scoreboards on Java edition and as far as I am aware the only scoreboard on Minecraft Bedrock is `dummy`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dummy scoreboard connected to a pressure plate at the persons spawnpoint. Then you could then have another command that teleports them to where you want them to technically appear after they die. This pressure plate and command could be in an enclosed bedrock space outside of the map. The command would also target the nearest player to the command block.